# how to create a simple circle mask CSS3 using clip-path?

Tags: css

I am trying to apply a circle clip to my picture

```
<style>
.circle {
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50%,50%,10%);
  clip-path: circle(50%,50%,10%);
};

</style>
</head>

<body>
<img src="image1.jpg" width="1024" height="768" alt="" class="circle"/>
</body>
```

and this simply doest not work

```css
.circle {
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50%,50%,10%);
  clip-path: circle(50%,50%,10%);
};
```

```html
<img src="http://cp91279.biography.com/Leonardo-da-Vinci_A-Divine-Mind_HD_768x432-16x9.jpg" width="1024" height="768" alt="" class="circle"/>
```

I don't want to use any border-radius !

Comment: Check out http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path, it appears that clip-path is not well supported and only works in fairly specific circumstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the the circle syntax is something more like

```
clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 10%);
```

so change to

```
.circle {
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 10%);
  clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 10%);
}
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fLgd4aw5/)

I found a mention of it [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/) on MDN

> circle([`<shape-radius>`] [at `<position>`]) The shape-radius argument is
>   the radius of the circle. The position argument defines the center
>   point of the circle and has the same syntax as background-position
>   (see background-position for details).

Nice explanation resource found [here](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/clip-path) on webplatform.org